# Performance of searching data through PHP vs SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, eloquent

My question is relevant to the concept of searching data. I am developing a project with Laravel.

The question is, which is efficient? **Get data from the database and search through PHP,** Or **prepare the SQL command and search inside the database.**

Description:

if  want to explain more, I face with this two types of coding:

```
$result = Model::where()->with()->...->paginate();
```

The other way:

```php
$result = Model::all();
$result->filter(function ($items) use ($search) {
    return ...;
});
```

Of course, these codes were simple.

Thanks

Comment: The only possible answer, with such a generic frame of reference is, "it depends". In most normal circumstances, you'd probably expect SQL to be better at that, since it's designed for manipulating and filtering large amounts of data efficiently. But that doesn't mean there might not be times where there are exceptions to that rule of thumb.

Comment: searching on what type of parameters? need more specific details as it depends. Most of the time, general searching is far better with SQL and with proper indexing and optimization it would be even better

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise, it is best practice to use SQL queries for searching data, but this is dependent on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It would help how you are measuring efficiency - quicker to write, easier to comprehend, faster to run, etc.

I would choose execution inside the database all the time when I can.

Imagine you are going to search through 100K records.

- If you were to filter at the application level, all those 100K records have to be sent over the network, and only then you can search.
- With `WHERE` clauses, the number of records will be very small and go easy on the network. This is because the filter will be applied in place.

That being said, I have been in situations where I couldn't filter at the DB level and had to filter at the application level. They were extremely slow, needless to say.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant by efficiency, is to execute faster and use fewer system resources.